# Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError in BooksController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-datastore

I tried [Using Cloud Datastore with Ruby](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) on my local machine(Win7 64), and got the following error:

```
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError in BooksController#index
7:Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Anyway, I could access the Cloud Datastore at the first time. Then I created the second project on the Google Cloud Platform. I want to access the Datastore in my second project. It failed.

I didn't know how it worked at the first time. I did [Sign Up](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate) and used `gcloud auth login` to authorize gcloud to access Google Cloud Platform.
In fact, I don't exactly understand these configurations.

Answer (score 0):

In my second project, I created an entity from Google Cloud Platform console.
Then I tried running my app locally, it could access Datastore this time.

How weird it is!

I created project3, insert an entity from Google Cloud Platform console and indeed it works.